# Add scripts to delay loading JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add more scripts to the code below, which forces JS to load after the page content. I'd like to add script2.js, script3.js, etc. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
  var element = document.createElement("script");

  element.src = "/home/site/script1.js";
  document.body.appendChild(element);
}

if (window.addEventListener)
  window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
  window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else
  window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just modify your load script function, in this way for example:

```js
function downloadJSAtOnload(scripts) {
  for (script in scripts) {
    let element = document.createElement("script");
    element.src = scripts[script];
    document.body.appendChild(element);    
  }  
}

let scripts = ["/home/site/script1.js","/home/site/script2.js","/home/site/script3.js"];

if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload.bind(downloadJSAtOnload, scripts), false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload.bind(downloadJSAtOnload, scripts));
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload.bind(downloadJSAtOnload, scripts);
```